# opendata : Web interface to let anyone create charts from my data

Tags: data-visualization, charts

I'd like to make data publicly available (opendata) to anyone, and let users create their own charts from my data. Ideally, they would be able to select the type of graph their want, group data into buckets, filter,etc.. (in the same way as [kibana lens](https://static-www.elastic.co/v3/assets/bltefdd0b53724fa2ce/bltf903fbfd6c4cc3c4/5fa3384424612d7400da24c4/illustrated-screenshot-hero-lens.png))

I found a lot of tools / software / websites to create visualisations from data but it's either intended for internal use (ex grafana) or for people to turn their own data into charts (ex rawgraphs.io), but haven't found anything that match my use-case.

I do not care if it's some library/software I have to add to my website or if it's a third-party website where I can just upload my data or connect my API and that will let users create their own charts. The less code I have to write, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look to [kaggle datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets). It has similar experience as a github but people are there mostly sharing datasets.

You can create data visualizations in a tool called a [kaggle code](https://www.kaggle.com/code), that lets you touch any data that are stored publicly. It has a similar experience to [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/), so it is pretty easy to start with. Please also mention, you can create visualizations without an account.

Type of visualizations are mentioned for example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/choosing-plot-types-and-custom-styles/tutorial).

**Pros**:

- lets you store approximately up to 20Gb of files per project which is very generous
- you can collaborate on a project with more people
- there are even competitions held out

**Cons**:

- not directly dashboarding capability (as for example in kibana) but for generating charts from data acceptable
- a bit of programming involved